# Mass PDF form fill

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I need to fill in a single PDF template multiple times and concat the results. When I say multiple, I mean up to a few hundred times, potentially over one thousand.

I can do this with `pdftk fill_form`, one by one, and then use `pdftk cat`. We can parallelize this fairly easily.

**I'm curious if this is the only option, or if there is a piece of software (Linux + OSX, command line) that will allow me to say "take this template, and these sets of fields, fill out this form, and concat the files" so I can avoid doing every one individually.** Then again, if something does exist, but it's not any faster than just doing the `fork` parallelization method, then it's probably not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

My Perl library [CAM::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CAM-PDF/) can do this. The form filling is a bit weak (it doesn't support checkboxes, for example) but the concatenation works great.

```
#perl -w                                                                            
use strict;
use CAM::PDF;

my $infile = 'in.pdf';
my $outfile = 'out.pdf';
my @fills = (
   { name => 'John' },
   { name => 'Fred' },
);

my $pdf = CAM::PDF->new($infile) or die $CAM::PDF::errstr;
for my $i (0 .. @fills-1) {
   my $filledPDF = $i == 0 ? $pdf : CAM::PDF->new($infile);
   $filledPDF->fillFormFields(%{$fills[$i]});
   if ($i > 0) {
      $pdf->appendPDF($filledPDF);
   }
}
$pdf->cleanoutput($outfile) or die;
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this answers your question exactly but this is how i do it.

```
for each objfile in colFiles
If right(objfile.Name,3) = "pdf" Then
FileFill = strFolderPath + "\" + objFile.Name
filled = strFolderPath + "\" + Replace(objFile.Name,".pdf", "_.pdf")
pdfnumber = Left(objfile.name,InStr(objFile.Name," ")-1)
set objFDF = objFSO.CreateTextFile(fdfform,true)
    objFDF.write "%FDF-1.2" & vbCrLf
    objFDF.write "%âãÏÓ" & vbCrLf
    objFDF.write "1 0 obj " & vbCrLf
    objFDF.write "<<" & vbCrLf
    objFDF.write "/FDF " & vbCrLf
    objFDF.write "<<" & vbCrLf
    objFDF.write "/Fields [" & vbCrLf
    objFDF.write "<<" & vbCrLf
    objFDF.write "/V (" & pdfnumber & ")" & vbCrLf
    objFDF.write "/T (Tekening nr)" & vbCrLf
    objFDF.write ">> " & vbCrLf
    'i have lots more inbetween
    objFDF.write ">>" & vbCrLf
    objFDF.write "endobj " & vbCrLf
    objFDF.write "trailer" & vbCrLf
    objFDF.write "" & vbCrLf
    objFDF.write "<<" & vbCrLf
    objFDF.write "/Root 1 0 R" & vbCrLf
    objFDF.write ">>" & vbCrLf
    objFDF.write "%%EOF" & vbCrLf
    objFDF.Close
    shl.run "cmd.exe /C pdftk """ & FileFill & """ fill_form """ & fdfform & """ output """ & filled & """"
    'wscript.echo "cmd.exe /C pdftk """ & FileFill & """ fill_form """ & fdfform & """ output """ & FileFill & """"
Wscript.sleep 1000
'objFSO.MoveFile strFolderPath + "\" + objFile.Name , strFolderPath + "\" + Replace(objFile.Name," ", "_")
fSO.DeleteFile(FileFill)
Wscript.sleep 1000
fSO.DeleteFile(fdfform)
Wscript.sleep 1000
Else
'nothing
end If
```

Next

This is just the section that handles the `fill_form` and `cat` so this code pasted in a vbs wont work but hopefully i can help you somewhat.

If you want to know how your .fdf needs to look you can run `pdftk test.pdf generate_fdf output outputFile.fdf` in CMD.

PS, not a programmer or engineer what so ever but im figuring this out myself so maybe i can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I see. Thanks for explaining! Am i wrong for commenting as a rookie? Im trying to learn the etiquettes of this site.

Comment: Ahh i just didnt read the question. Also, its a question from 12 years ago haha. My bad.